# Going a level up in the src path of the <script src=""></script> tag in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have folder structure as below.

[image]

Where I have `index.html` file in `html_files` folder.

I am using the script tag as below in my `index.html` file.

[image]

but the jQuery function `hide()` is not working. Am I doing anything wrong here..? Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Hide function is not bound to any event. Which event do you wish to trigger the hide function? I belive you wish to fire it when you open the page right? But when you open the page script runs before the elements are created and there are no h1 to find it and hide it. if you wrap it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1').hide();
});
```

Now it will wait for the document to create elements then run hide() function.

Another Scenario is you want to hide it when you click a button, then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('h1').hide();
  });
});
```

Now, it waits all the elements to be ready then bind hide() function to button's click event.

Comment: I am trying to hide the `h1` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your `hide()` call is bound to an event. This shorthand for `$(document).ready()` should help you out:

```
$(function() {
  $('h1').hide();
});
```

Refer to http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ for more information.